# Mongodb query Aggregate Documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have many rows like this in my mongodb collection.Please note that within "category" there are many key value pairs.

Is there a way I can write an aggregated query to sum all the values inside of the category with a predicate on the date like Date:/20130202/ so tht it fetches all rows starting with 20130202 and also sums up values sport, national, int, finance etc and outputs the values ie.

> sport: 42 , national: 6, international: 11, finance: 9, others:17, tech: 20, Music: 34

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51c34a871d56bd16c34e7887"),
  "Date" : "2013020219",
  "category" : { 
    "sport" : 40,
    "national" : 2,
    "international" : 6, 
    "finance" : 2,
    "others" : 16,
    "tech" : 10,
    "Music" : 32
  }
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51c34a871d56bd16c34e7887"),
  "Date" : "2013020218",
  "category" : { 
    "sport" : 2,
    "national" : 4,
    "international" : 5,
    "finance" : 7,
    "others" : 1,
    "tech" : 10,
    "Music" : 2
  }
```

}

Comment: It seems like you'd just write an aggregation to group on the data, and then `$sum` each `category` by name (`category.sport`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
db.coll.aggregate( [
   { $match: { Date: /20130202/ } },
   { $group: { _id: null,
                sport: { $sum: "$category.sport" },
                national: { $sum: "$category.national" },
                international: { $sum: "$category.international" },
                finance: { $sum: "$category.finance" },
                others: { $sum: "$category.others" },
                tech: { $sum: "$category.tech" },
                Music: { $sum: "$category.Music" }   
              } }
] )
```